# Hermitian conjugate of a matrix with operators, Python, sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a matrix which contains operators. I want to take its hermitian conjugate.

```
from sympy import Matrix, symbols
from sympy.physics.quantum import Operator
from sympy.physics.secondquant import Dagger

A, B = symbols('A, B', cls=Operator)
mat = Matrix([[0, A*B], [0, 0]])
print(mat.H)
print(Dagger(mat))
```

What I expect to get is

```
Matrix([[0, 0], [Dagger(B)*Dagger(A), 0]])
```

However, from mat.H I receive

```
Matrix([[0, 0], [conjugate(A)*conjugate(B), 0]])
```

and from Dagger(mat)

```
Dagger(Matrix([
[0, A*B],
[0,   0]]))
```

Is there any way I can do it in sympy?

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/16959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually transpose and apply the dagger to each element:

```
In [38]: mat.transpose().applyfunc(Dagger)                                                                                        
Out[38]: 
⎡         0           0⎤
⎢                      ⎥
⎣Dagger(B)⋅Dagger(A)  0⎦
```